# Find all other records for an ID if a record exists

Tags: sql

I need to find all other related records for an ID if a certain value exists.

I have almost no SQL experience and work primarily on a front end design UI, rather than writing the code myself.

The basic query is:

For a given period, if any customer placed an order in that period, I'd like to see all orders for those customers.

So looking for all orders for any customer who placed an order in April:

```
Customer Order   Month
John     Apples  January
John     Pears   January
John     Oranges February
John     Bananas April
Amy      Apples  March
Amy      Pears   May
Amy      Oranges July
Amy      Bananas September
Larry    Apples  January
Larry    Pears   April
Larry    Oranges August
Larry    Bananas November
Marge    Apples  April
Marge    Pears   May
Marge    Oranges June
Marge    Bananas July
```

Expected result would be:

```
Customer Order   Month
John     Apples  January
John     Pears   January
John     Oranges February
John     Bananas April
Larry    Apples  January
Larry    Pears   April
Larry    Oranges August
Larry    Bananas November
Marge    Apples  April
Marge    Pears   May
Marge    Oranges June
Marge    Bananas July
```

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think what you want to do is join the table to itself. You need to make a query where you get all the DISTINCT names for customers that placed orders in April. Then you can join the results of this query back to the orders table and select each row where the customer name appears in the first result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write it literally like your described it:  Find all the customers from April and then show all the orders for those customers.

```
SELECT * FROM OrderTable ot WHERE ot.Customer IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Customer FROM OrderTable WHERE Month = 'April')
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use `EXISTS` and a correlated subquery that checks if there is a record from April for the name.

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                            FROM elbat t2
                            WHERE t2.name = t1.name
                                  AND t2.month = 'April');
```

Another one is to use a derived table for all records of April and join the other records on the common name.

```
SELECT t2.*
       FROM (SELECT t1.name
                    FROM elbat t1
                    WHERE t1.month = 'April') x
            INNER JOIN elbat t2
                       ON t2.name = x.name;
```

Comment: These are both better than using `IN` with `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: "Better" How?  Performance?  Probably.  I didn't consider performance at all.   Simplicity and Readability sometimes count more than anything... Especially to people who are just trying to learn.